# How can I find unique hotels from database [Mysql], when duplicates inserted by multiple suppliers?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I am working on a hotel web application, here I have multiple supplier those can insert same hotel with different details. How can i filter the duplicate hotel in database? Not started to code yet just an idea

Comment: Try something from your side first. Then add some more information about the table structure, sample data and all. To find the distinct value for one column is very easy, it seems that you didn't check this and directly ask the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. You should first try on your own and learn from the experience. You should even start with a small database and use some sample data to get accustomed with the terms and tools.

You can achieve the de-duplication simply by using the `DISTINCT` keyword in SQL. [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp](http://DISTINCT%20Reference)

Comment: I inserted the data from roomsxml.com and www.jactravel.co.uk, but I found that there are many duplicate hotels. I tried dinstinct of mysql then check hotel based on city and country with same name. But same hotel has country USA and other has with united states. so no luck. I also carried out some internet research about weka I just want to know can weka help or I should learn algorithms for that.

Comment: Now you're asking a completly different question. And harmonizing data from different sources is definitly off-topic for stackoverflow, sorry. You can always try to harmonize manually (i.e. "USA" and "United States of America" both link to the same entry in a "country" table).

Comment: Yes Stefan, data harmonizing may be off the topic but asking question is a good thing I think. I just got an idea of using google places to compare address and I think it is worth trying. checking entries manually will be my last option. But I appreciate your comment.